# Get complete response logs in the logcat monitor?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, response, android-logcat

The response coming from server is too long. So I am not able to see the complete response in the logcat monitor in android studio.

Is there any way to get the complete logcat of the response ?

Comment: You could store the answer in a file that you can read out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you should use debug points. You can get complete response and can see step by step execution of your code. For more you can go into the below website :

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Yes , its the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom class for this. The important method for using it inside your code is splitAndLog by @pctroll.

```
  public class Utils {
        /**
         * Divides a string into chunks of a given character size.
         * 
         * @param text                  String text to be sliced
         * @param sliceSize             int Number of characters
         * @return  ArrayList<String>   Chunks of strings
         */
        public static ArrayList<String> splitString(String text, int sliceSize) {
            ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String aux;
            int left = -1, right = 0;
            int charsLeft = text.length();
            while (charsLeft != 0) {
                left = right;
                if (charsLeft >= sliceSize) {
                    right += sliceSize;
                    charsLeft -= sliceSize;
                }
                else {
                    right = text.length();
                    aux = text.substring(left, right);
                    charsLeft = 0;
                }
                aux = text.substring(left, right);
                textList.add(aux);
            }
            return textList;
        }

        /**
         * Divides a string into chunks.
         * 
         * @param text                  String text to be sliced
         * @return  ArrayList<String>   
         */
        public static ArrayList<String> splitString(String text) {
            return splitString(text, 80);
        }

        /**
         * Divides the string into chunks for displaying them
         * into the Eclipse's LogCat.
         * 
         * @param text      The text to be split and shown in LogCat
         * @param tag       The tag in which it will be shown.
         */
        public static void splitAndLog(String tag, String text) {
            ArrayList<String> messageList = Utils.splitString(text);
            for (String message : messageList) {
                Log.d(tag, message);
            }
        }
    }
```